# Program for simulate (strongly) load on php site

Tags: php, testing, load, simulation

I want simulate load on site, (site is write on php). for example I want simulate simultaneous 10 000 request on same page (for example index.php), after search I found "jmeter" (but I still not test it). Other, what program you can recommend for this?

Comment: i would not start with 10k in case it breaks things but work up to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apache Bench. It is a command line load tester. If you want to test 10,000 simultaneous users use this command line :

```
ab -c 10000 http://www.mysite.com/
```

-c is the number of concurrent requests..

Comment: Warning - I had my IP blocked on dreamhost after running one of these tests, so be careful.

Comment: @Mulhoon: Well you should never try load testing on a LIVE server, especially if it is a shared hosting service like dreamhost. Load tests should only be done on staging/testing environments!!

Answer (score 1):

[`ApacheBench`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) is great for this sort of thing, and is probably already installed on your machine.